# Stuck Run Activity from Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity

i have some code in android studio. i want calling this activity :

```
public void addConversationFragmentStartCall(ArrayList<Integer> opponents,
                                             QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType qbConferenceType, Map<String, String> userInfo) {
    QBRTCSession newSessionWithOpponents = rtcClient.createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponents, qbConferenceType);
    SettingsUtil.setSettingsStrategy(opponents, getDefaultSharedPrefs(), this);

    Log.d("Crash", "addConversationFragmentStartCall. Set session " + newSessionWithOpponents);
    initCurrentSession(newSessionWithOpponents);
    ConversationFragment fragment = ConversationFragment.newInstance(opponents, "jinkal", qbConferenceType,
            userInfo, StartConversetionReason.OUTCOME_CALL_MADE, getCurrentSession().getSessionID());
    FragmentExecuotr.addFragment(getFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment_container, fragment,
            CONVERSATION_CALL_FRAGMENT);

    if (ringtonePlayer != null) {
        ringtonePlayer = new RingtonePlayer(this, R.raw.beep);
    }
    ringtonePlayer.play(true);
}
```

i call from fragment with click button with this code :

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
            ((VideoCallActivity) getActivity()).addConversationFragmentStartCall(
                    oponent, qbConferenceType, userInfo);
                callStatus = 1;
            }
```

But stuck and get error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.going.pass.MainDrawerActivity cannot be cast to com.going.pass.activity.VideoCallActivity

my code in fragment use this

> class UberTripFragment extends UberBaseFragment

where in UberBaseFragment contain this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = (MainDrawerActivity) getActivity();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);

}
```

Please help how fix this..

Answer (score 0):

The fragment where this is called:

```
if (getActivity() != null) 
{
        ((VideoCallActivity) getActivity()).addConversationFragmentStartCall(
                oponent, qbConferenceType, userInfo);
            callStatus = 1;
}
```

Is attached to your MainDrawerActivity, it has to be attached to your VideoCallActivity.

Comment: so, how make calling public void addConversationFragmentStartCall from my fragment?

Comment: up again help please

Comment: Add your fragment to the VideoCallActivity instead of the MainDrawerActivity. getActivity() returns the activity that contains the fragment